# Need help connecting node.js to angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Ok I knew mongodb, node.js and very little about angular.js... and at some point I got struck, so I deliberately need help. I knew the node.js code but can't understand how to retrieve it through angular.js. Please write angular.js code how to get data from this given node.js code. If any error in my node.js code please notify me.

```
var express = require('express');
app = express(); // Web framework to handle routing requests
cons = require('consolidate'); // Templating library adapter for Express
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; // Driver for connecting to MongoDB
routes = require('./routes'); // Routes for our application
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/blog', function(err, db) {
    "use strict";
    if(err) throw err;
    
    // Register our templating engine
    app.engine('html', cons.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
    
    // Express middleware to populate 'req.cookies' so we can access cookies
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    
    // Express middleware to populate 'req.body' so we can access POST variables
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    
    // The main page of the blog
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
           Post.find(function(err, posts){
                  if(err){ return next(err); }

                  res.json(posts);
            });
    });     
    
    app.listen(8082);
    console.log('Express server listening on port 8082');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Post is not defined?

Maybe

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
```

Then using ngResource for obtain the data from api

```
app.factory('allPosts', function($resource){
return $resource('/');});
```